# How to group the field in 1 line in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I'm using this MS SQL Script:

```
     select NumberId, ART_No, InkColor 
     from INK_STOCK
```

and I have an output like this:

```
     NumberId         ART_No          InkColor
     ------------------------------------------
     0010             23003             BLUE
     0010             23003             RED
     0010             23003             GREEN
     0013             23004             ORANGE
     0013             23004             PINK
     0013             23004             WHITE
     0015             23007             GREEN
     0015             23007             PINK
```

How can I make the output should be like this:

```
     NumberId         ART_No          InkColor
     ------------------------------------------
     0010             23003             BLUE, RED, GREEN
     0013             23004             ORANGE, PINK, WHITE
     0015             23007             GREEN, PINK
```

Thanks

Comment: http://explainextended.com/2010/06/21/group_concat-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEexample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e8a2/8)**

```
select c1.NumberId, c1.ART_No,
    STUFF((   SELECT ', ' +x.InkColor
        FROM INK_STOCK x
        WHERE c1.NumberId = x.NumberId
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ),1,1,'') as InkColor
from INK_STOCK c1
group by c1.NumberId, c1.ART_No
```

Result:

```
| NUMBERID | ART_NO |             INKCOLOR |
--------------------------------------------
|       10 |  23003 |     BLUE, RED, GREEN |
|       13 |  23004 |  ORANGE, PINK, WHITE |
|       15 |  23007 |          GREEN, PINK |
```